# Выводит \r в rails console

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, ruby, archlinux

Здравствуйте, проблема возникла, при входе в консоль rails c при нажатии enter выводится дополнительно \r. Не знаю как от этого избавится((.

```
[icestranger@arch_notebook_jul equip]$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 3985
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.1)

irb: warn: can't alias context from irb_context.
2.3.1 :001 > \r
2.3.1 :002 >   \r
2.3.1 :003 >   \r
2.3.1 :004 >   \r
2.3.1 :005 >   \r
2.3.1 :006 >   \r
2.3.1 :007 >   \r
2.3.1 :008 >   \r
2.3.1 :009 >   \r
2.3.1 :010 >   \r
2.3.1 :011 >   \r
2.3.1 :012 >   \r
2.3.1 :013 >   \r
2.3.1 :014 >   \r
2.3.1 :015 >   \r
2.3.1 :016 >   \r
```

сравнение переменных окружения (в первом случае — «всё работает», во втором — описанная ошибка):

```
$ diff -ruaN <(sort ~/ssh_env) <(sort ~/env_local)
--- /dev/fd/63  2017-05-12 17:01:55.398959870 +0500
+++ /dev/fd/62  2017-05-12 17:01:55.358960428 +0500
@@ -1,38 +1,45 @@
-GEM_HOME=/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
-GEM_PATH=/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1:/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global
-HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
-HISTSIZE=1000
-HOME=/home/deployer
-HOSTNAME=workproject1.testing.cloud.iit.csu.ru
-IRBRC=/home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/.irbrc
+COLORFGBG=default;default
+COLORTERM=rxvt
+DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
+DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID=awesome/equip/608-33-arch_notebook_jul_TIME10177187
+DISPLAY=:0
+GEM_HOME=/home/icestranger/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@equip
+GEM_PATH=/home/icestranger/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@equip:/home/icestranger/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global
+HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
+HISTFILESIZE=10000
+HISTIGNORE=ls:ps:history
+HISTTIMEFORMAT=%h %d %H:%M:%S 
+HOME=/home/icestranger
+IRBRC=/home/icestranger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/.irbrc
 LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
-LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
-LOGNAME=deployer
-LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
-MAIL=/var/spool/mail/deployer
-MY_RUBY_HOME=/home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1
-PATH=/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/deployer/.local/bin:/home/deployer/bin:/home/deployer/.rvm/bin
-PWD=/home/deployer
+LOGNAME=icestranger
+MAIL=/var/spool/mail/icestranger
+MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
+MY_RUBY_HOME=/home/icestranger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1
+PATH=/home/icestranger/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@equip/bin:/home/icestranger/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/home/icestranger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/home/icestranger/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
+PWD=/home/icestranger/work/parsing/equip
 RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.3.1
-rvm_bin_path=/home/deployer/.rvm/bin
-rvm_path=/home/deployer/.rvm
-rvm_prefix=/home/deployer
-rvm_version=1.27.0 (latest)
-SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
-SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
-SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
+rvm_bin_path=/home/icestranger/.rvm/bin
+rvm_delete_flag=0
+rvm_path=/home/icestranger/.rvm
+rvm_prefix=/home/icestranger
+rvm_ruby_string=ruby-2.3.1
+rvm_version=1.28.0 (latest)
 SHELL=/bin/bash
-SHLVL=1
-SSH_CLIENT=94.25.183.9 26207 22
-SSH_CONNECTION=94.25.183.9 26207 10.253.2.11 22
-SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
+SHLVL=3
+SSH_AGENT_PID=616
+SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-irg6jQlKqJaR/agent.615
 _system_arch=x86_64
-_system_name=CentOS
+_system_name=Arch
 _system_type=Linux
-_system_version=7
+_system_version=libc-2.25
 TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color
-USER=deployer
+USER=icestranger
 _=/usr/bin/env
+WINDOWID=4194552
+WINDOWPATH=1
+XAUTHORITY=/home/icestranger/.Xauthority
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
-XDG_SESSION_ID=38926
+XDG_SEAT=seat0
+XDG_SESSION_ID=c1
+XDG_VTNR=1
```

Comment: Вот теперь хорошо. А просто в `irb` где-нибудь далеко, а-ля в домашней папке, эффект воспроизводится?

Comment: нет, даже в этой папке нет, но именно "rails c" везде так работает

Comment: в качестве терминала используется urxvt, но я и пробовал и без загрузки Х(графической оболчки) в терминале запускать такая же ерунда. Почти первая, первая это переход где есть rails.

Comment: если в этом же терминале по ssh подключится к серверу и там запустить "rails c" то всё нормально

Comment: вы работаете под разными пользователями. «по ssh» — `deployer`, локально — `icestranger`. соотвественно, получаете совершенно разные рабочие каталоги и файлы, и сравнение **лишь** переменных окружение лишено смысла. // *А какие лишние комментарии?* — например, те, которые адресовались мне, а я их уже явно прочитал.

Comment: Кстати, совет на будущее, чтобы делать разницу переменных окружения, стоит файлы "обработать" перед тем как, а именно в данном случае а) заменить все вхождения `icestranger` на `deployer` во втором файле, и б) отсортировать их. Тогда разница станет меньше и понятнее.